# Background Border issue in Navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of trouble in regards to background color being applied to all at once to pages within a part of my navigation section. Currently when I hover over Brass, the background color is being applied to Brass and the pages within this section. What I'm trying to accomplish is getting the background color to appear only when I hover over these elements instead of all at once.

```css
header {
  color: #348899;
  background-color: #343642;
  background-image: url(Images/heading.png);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 42pt;
  line-height: 36pt;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 5px;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height: 22pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 5px 0;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height: 22pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
nav {
  color: #343642;
  background-color: #979C9C;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 100%;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #b1b6b6;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #343642;
}
nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  right: 35%;
}
nav ul li:hover ul  {
  display: block;
}
nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
main {
  color: #17354A;
  background-color: #F2EBC7;
  margin-left: 160px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.column  {
  float: left;
}
.left {
  width: 75%;
}
.right {
  width: 25%;
}
.text {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
main .row .left {
  width: 25%;
}
main .row .middle {
  width: 50%;
}
main .row .right {
  width: 25%;
}
.brass {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.logo {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
body{
  background-color: #348899;
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
footer {
  color: #348899;
  background-color: #343642;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Beginning Band Players - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>
        Beginning Band Players
      </h1>
      <h2>
        Home
      </h2>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Brass</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Brass/trumpet.html">Trumpet</a></li>
            <li><a href="Brass/frenchhorn.html">Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="Brass/trombone.html">Trombone</a></li>
            <li><a href="Brass/euphonium.html">Euphonium</a></li>
            <li><a href="Brass/tuba.html">Tuba</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Woodwind</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Woodwind/clarinet.html">Clarinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="Woodwind/flute.html">Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="Woodwind/oboe.html">Oboe</a></li>
            <li><a href="Woodwind/saxophone.html">Saxophone</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Percussion</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Percussion/bells.html">Bells</a></li>
            <li><a href="Percussion/snare.html">Snare Drum</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Maintenence</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional Equipment</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <div class="column left">
        <div class="logo">
         <img src="Images/Logo-E.png" alt="logo" height="200" width="355">
        </div>
        <h3>
         About us:
        </h3>
        <div class="text">
          <p>
            The purpose of Beginning Band Players is to provide students and parents
            with the necessary resources for a successful start in any band program.
            It's our hope that prospective music students find what they're looking
            for and enjoy a lifetime of music.
          </p>
          <div class="brass">
            <img src="Images/brass-1.jpg" alt="brass" height="238" width="425">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column right">
        <h3>
          What to Expect:
        </h3>
        <p>
          Students can learn a little about each instrument found in beginning band
          programs and decide which one they like best. They'll be able to see and
          hear what each instrument sounds like.
        </p>
        <h3>
          Additional Resources:
        </h3>
        <p>
          Students may also need additional equipment such as practice books or supplies
          to help maintain their instruments. Links to such supplies can be found on the
          Additional Equipment page.
        </p>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Copyright &copy; 2022, Carter Thomas Wolfe <br>
      Web Project Prototype
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apply a background-color to the sub-menu instead of default value from main menu

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Comment: `nav ul li ul{ background-color: #979C9C;}`

Comment: That's not exactly doing what I'm wanting

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted , if you can be more specific it will be easy to answer accurately . If you can add screenshot of what you want then it will be good

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background-color: #b1b6b6;
}
```

instead of

```
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #b1b6b6;
}
```

Comment: Or use [this](https://codepen.io/ysilavi/pen/NWvxRdj?editors=1100) (Hover on 'Home' item)